# RewriteRule command in my .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, cpanel

i recently bought a php website which used RewriteRule in .htaccess to redirect urls, such as domain.com/login to be redirected to domain.com/login.php or /register to /register.php and so on. these are the contents of my .htaccess file :

```
options -multiviews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^users$ users.php
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php
RewriteRule ^logout$ logout.php
RewriteRule ^log_out$ log_out.php
RewriteRule ^forgot$ forgot.php
RewriteRule ^manage_gigs$ manage_gigs.php
RewriteRule ^manage_orders$ manage_orders.php
RewriteRule ^new$ new.php
RewriteRule ^suggestions$ index.php
RewriteRule ^search$ search.php
RewriteRule ^edit$ edit.php
RewriteRule ^edit_extra$ edit_extra.php
RewriteRule ^bookmark$ bookmark.php
RewriteRule ^bookmarks$ bookmarks.php
RewriteRule ^settings$ settings.php
RewriteRule ^balance$ balance.php
RewriteRule ^order$ order.php
RewriteRule ^orders$ orders.php
RewriteRule ^inbox$ inbox.php
RewriteRule ^conversations/([^/.]*)?$ conversations.php?u=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^upload$ upload.php
RewriteRule ^check_new$ check_new.php
RewriteRule ^spam$ spam.php
RewriteRule ^thank_you$ thank_you.php
RewriteRule ^track$ track.php
RewriteRule ^send_track$ send_track.php
RewriteRule ^confirmemail$ confirmemail.php
RewriteRule ^rss$ rss.php
RewriteRule ^terms_of_service$ terms_of_service.php
RewriteRule ^privacy_policy$ privacy_policy.php
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php
RewriteRule ^advertising$ advertising.php
RewriteRule ^signup$ signup.php
RewriteRule ^forgotpassword$ forgotpassword.php
RewriteRule ^feature$ feature.php
RewriteRule ^feature_success$ feature_success.php
RewriteRule ^purchases$ purchases.php
RewriteRule ^suggested$ suggested.php
RewriteRule ^mysuggestions$ mysuggestions.php
RewriteRule ^myreferrals$ myreferrals.php
RewriteRule ^levels$ levels.php
RewriteRule ^categories/([^/.]+)?$ cat.php?cid=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^user/([^/.]+)?$ user.php?uname=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)?$ tags.php?cid=$1&tag=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]*)?$ view.php?title=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c> 
   # Turn off mod_security filtering. 
   SecFilterEngine Off 

   # The below probably isn't needed, 
   # but better safe than sorry. 
   SecFilterScanPOST Off 
</IfModule>
```

but clicking any link goes to a 404 error (page not found) because urls are not redirected. i am using cpanel. do i have to activate some function to make it work ? what could possibly be wrong here ? thanks.

Comment: IS `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` activated?

Comment: hi, can you please tell me how to check it, and if not, how to activate it ? thanks !

Comment: It inefficient to use mod_rewrite, for most of your redirections you could just use the Redirect directive instead. Redirect [Original] [Target] For example: Redirect /users users.php

Comment: after doing what you said, i get a 500 Internal Server error ! it says (The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.) what is the problem ? thanks.

Comment: Take a look in the apache error log and it should give you something to go on.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't have rewrite rule enabled.

1. Open `httpd.conf`;
2. Find the line, where `mod_rewrite.so` is mentioned;
3. Remove the hashtag ( `#` ) at the front;
4. Restart your webserver;

Comment: hello, i use cpanel, but i am new in it. can you tell me where can i find the file httpd.conf ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change
`RewriteBase /`
By
`RewriteBase / Your folder /`